# Are other threads suspended during DLL_THREAD_ATTACH in dllmain

Tags: c++, windows

I have to modify a `std::vector` during `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`. Do I have to use a critical section or are the other threads suspended at this moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are not suspended while a DLL loads.

Comment: jou are right. I'd been asking the wrong way. Asking the correct question, its obvious. Thanks!